# Error python packages version: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.7.1) or chardet (2.0.1) doesn't match a supported version

Tags: python, version, requirements.txt

I am a python newbie and I am trying to run https://github.com/epinna/tplmap

requirements.txt

```
PyYAML==3.12
certifi==2017.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.6
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

After downloading the project from Github I run `sudo pip intall -r requirements.txt` and when I try to run the tplmap.py file I get this error

```
$ ./tplmap.py -u 'localhost:3000'
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.7.1) or chardet (2.0.1) doesn't match a supported version!
      RequestsDependencyWarning)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./tplmap.py", line 3, in <module>
        from core import checks
      File "/home/amion/Desktop/tplmap-master/core/checks.py", line 20, in <module>
        from core.channel import Channel
      File "/home/amion/Desktop/tplmap-master/core/channel.py", line 1, in <module>
        import requests
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
        from urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
    ImportError: cannot import name DependencyWarning
```

I look at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py` file and see:

```
# urllib3 >= 1.21.1, <= 1.22
# chardet >= 3.0.2, < 3.1.0
```

If I run pip freeze I see:

```
chardet==3.0.4
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
```

I don't understand this message, where do those version numbers come form? what I am missing?

```
 RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.7.1) or chardet (2.0.1) doesn't match a supported version!
```

Comment: try running `pip install -r requirements.txt` without `sudo`

Comment: @wpercy I uninstalled all the requirements and installed them without sudo and with the --user option after deleting urlib3 and chardet from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I deleted urlib3 and chardet directories from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Then I uninstalled all the requirements from the requirements.txt file and installed them again without sudo and with the --user option

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
sudo rm -r urllib3/
sudo rm -r chardet/

cd /home/amion/Desktop/tplmap-master
sudo pip uninstall -r requirements.txt 
pip install -r requirements.txt --user
```

It seems tplmap.py was trying to work with urllib3 and chardet from directory

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

and not from directory

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```